# Calculate the total time taken from dates in multiple columns in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I want to calculate the time difference in hours and show it in a new column.

For example time taken from Initial Contact (A2) to Response Time (B2) and show it in E2. AND time taken from F/U Contact (C4) to Response Time (D4) and show it in E4.

[image]

Comment: How does one know the two lines 2 and 4 are linked? why not 2 and 5?

Comment: Each row is independent of each other. They are not linked. I'm trying to write a formula to calculate the time taken to respond. Unfortunately the result has to be in the column E. For example E2 = B2-A2. or E4=D4-C4

Comment: But you are saying B2-A2 And D4-C4 both belong in E2.  I am trying to figure out the relation as to why both should be in the same cell.

Comment: The values I get in column E will be further used to analyze Average Response Time, On Time Response, Delayed Response etc. Hence I need all the results to be in column E.

Comment: But you state the results from row 2 AND row 4 results should both be in the same cell E2.  Is that a typo?

Comment: I'm so embarrassed right now! It's been a long week! The results should show in their respective rows. E2 = (B2-A2), E3 = (B3-A3), E4 = (D4-C4), E5=(D5-C5). Thank You.

Comment: `=SUM(-A2,B2,-C2,D2)` then format it `[hh]:mm`

Comment: It Worked! Thank you so much! I don't know how to up vote this. This is my first time in Stackoverflow. But I'll figure it out!

Comment: You can't upvote comments and I do not have time to correctly write up an answer.  Feel free to write up your own answer, then after 24 hours you can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer and thanks to Scott Craner. I had tried different formulas like DATEDIF, IF etc and nothing worked. But the below formula suggested by Scott worked like magic!

`=SUM(-A2,B2,-C2,D2)` and format the cell to display time in hours and minutes `[h]:mm`.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5ekE.jpg)